# replacing with A-19 Halogen bulbs

Tags: light-fixture, halogen

I am thinking to replace the regular CFL bulb on a light fixture to a 'Smart Guardian 42-Watt Halogen A-19 Clear 6-Hour Cycle Timer Light Bulb', but because its called 'Halogen', I am little concerned about the heat that it could generate as the light figure has a glass cover dome. Any suggestions on this? I plan to be away from home while this light comes on and I dont want to take any chance. TIA.
--Shiva.

Comment: Did the fixture come with the CFL? Is there a wattage limit listed on the fixture or in the literature?

Answer (score 1):

A 42W bulb is only going to produce 42 Watts of heat (well, a little less since some of the energy escapes as light (roughly 3 - 5% for a halogen)).

So as long as the fixture is rated for at least 42 watts, that bulb will be fine. The max wattage limit should be noted on the fixture somewhere, either on a sticker, or embossed in the metal.

I think your fear of the word "halogen" comes from the [number of accidents](http://www.cpsc.gov/en/Recalls/1997/CPSC-and-Industry-Announce-Corrective-Action-to-Improve-Safety-of-Halogen-Torchiere-Floor-Lamps/) attributable to 300W and 500W halogen floor lamps with exposed bulbs, these concerns have been mostly addressed with new safety features (primary guards over the bulbs). But a 42W replacement bulb doesn't pose the same hazard.

Comment: I agree for the most part, a 42w halogen lamp is tiny compared to other 42w lamps, but to a fixture it should be the same. +

Comment: @EdBeal - do you mean tiny in size? The bulb mentioned in the question looks like it's the same as any other A19: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Smart-Electric-Smart-Guardian-42-Watt-Halogen-A-19-Clear-6-Hour-Cycle-Timer-Light-Bulb-261/205168117

Comment: I did mean tiny in size I have some 120v halogens that have a lamp that is at most 3/8" by maybe 3/4" long that are 75 maybe 100w they have a quarts globe that if touched with finger oils they explode because of the heat. Not really had any other lamps do that as bad. But if the fixture says 40/50/60w the 42 w should be just fine as that is the power or heat generated by the bulb.

Comment: @EdBeal - Ahh ok, I think you have something like this [candelabra base 75W T4 halogen](https://www.1000bulbs.com/product/5065/Q-JD10080.html) with an exposed capsule. The A19 lookalikes have a protective glass globe that surrounds the capsule. But as you say, the size of the bulb doesn's matter, just the wattage.